Getting NoSuchMethodError while restoring Flink job from a savepoint
I'm using Apache Flink with version 1.16.1. When I deploy a job with fromSavepoint option, I get error below;
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine.hasOption(Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Option;)Z
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontendParser.createSavepointRestoreSettings(CliFrontendParser.java:631) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.ProgramOptions.<init>(ProgramOptions.java:119) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.ProgramOptions.create(ProgramOptions.java:192) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:230) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836) ~[flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-10.0.jar:2.8.3-10.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165) [flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]"

This seems like version mismatch issue of commons-cli. Version commons-cli must be 1.5.0 at least to deploy the job, but it's not able to do it. I checked every package in the maven file and there is no package below 1.5.0. There is an interesting thing here;
This is the source code of the thing above;
    public static SavepointRestoreSettings createSavepointRestoreSettings(CommandLine commandLine) {
        if (commandLine.hasOption(SAVEPOINT_PATH_OPTION.getOpt())) {
            String savepointPath = commandLine.getOptionValue(SAVEPOINT_PATH_OPTION.getOpt());
            boolean allowNonRestoredState =
                    commandLine.hasOption(SAVEPOINT_ALLOW_NON_RESTORED_OPTION.getOpt());
            final RestoreMode restoreMode;
            if (commandLine.hasOption(SAVEPOINT_RESTORE_MODE)) {
                restoreMode =
                        ConfigurationUtils.convertValue(
                                commandLine.getOptionValue(SAVEPOINT_RESTORE_MODE),
                                RestoreMode.class);
            } else {
                restoreMode = SavepointConfigOptions.RESTORE_MODE.defaultValue();
            }
            return SavepointRestoreSettings.forPath(
                    savepointPath, allowNonRestoredState, restoreMode);
        } else {
            return SavepointRestoreSettings.none();
        }
    }

Job fails at java:631 -> if (commandLine.hasOption(SAVEPOINT_RESTORE_MODE)). It throws exception here, but the similar control exist above (5 lines above) java:626 if (commandLine.hasOption(SAVEPOINT_PATH_OPTION.getOpt())). As you can see here, the second one does not have .getOpt method which probably causes a problem here. What can I do to solve this problem?
Edit:
To make sure there is no problem with the code, I've run code below;
    val opt = new Option("rm", "restoreMode", true, "Defines how should we restore from the given savepoint. Supported options: " + "[claim - claim ownership of the savepoint and delete once it is" + " subsumed, no_claim (default) - do not claim ownership, the first" + " checkpoint will not reuse any files from the restored one, legacy " + "- the old behaviour, do not assume ownership of the savepoint files," + " but can reuse some shared files.")

    val cl = new CommandLine.Builder().build()

    if (cl.hasOption(opt.getOpt)) {
     logger.error("l!")
    } else {
      logger.error("p!")
    }

    if (cl.hasOption(opt)) {
      logger.error("y!")
    }
    else {
      logger.error("x!")
    }

it didn't throw any exception. Here seems like there is no problem with versions etc. But why does Flink throws exception in the same situation?

As you noted, normally this error indicates that there's an incompatible (in your case, older) version of the jar on the classpath. Just checking Maven dependencies isn't sufficient, as Flink's classpath is dynamically built, and very complex. I assume you've read the Debugging Classloading page, and thus have tried the classloader.resolve-order config voodoo.
I've sometimes had to use the JarHell code from the OpenSearch project to debug these problems. Often you have to edit it to remove conflicts that are unavoidable in Flink, before you finally get to the root of your problem.

Thank you! I've tried classloader.resolve-order conf but it didn't work. The thing I can't understand is that why Flink does not throw the same exception when I use the same function (defined in the edit section). I use the same packages but it works in my case. Whenever Flink uses it to parse args, it fails.

With classpath issues, it can be tricky. If the path of the code for Flink is slightly different, the order in which jars/classes get added to the classpath can be different. You can sometimes use a JVM tool like YourKit to track down exactly what's happening, but I find it easier to just figure out where the incompatible jar is coming from.

I checked all the packages, only hadoop-common contains commons-cli 1.2 version. I removed it but problem still continues. I can't detect the root package that contains mismatch version. Maybe flink-shaded-hadoop-2 package contains it, but I couldn't find it as well.

When you deploy your job, if it's running in k8s or YARN, other jars can get added to the classpath by the Flink runtime. So that's why sometimes the only way to debug the issue is to use JarHell to find conflicts dynamically (at the instant that the code is running), versus static analysis.
